# Handlebars + handlebars-helper-prettify in node.js: empty result

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I try to use Handlebars with the [prettify helper](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helper-prettify) using the following code:

```
var handlebars = require("handlebars");
var helpers = require('prettify');

var templateHtml = "{{#prettify}}<div class='entry'><h1>{{title}}</h1><div class='body'>{{body}}</div></div>{{/prettify}}";
var templater = handlebars.compile(templateHtml);
var transformedHtml = templater({
    title: "Hello World",
    body: "De kat krabt de krullen van de trap"
});
console.log(transformedHtml);
```

But I get an empty result. What am I missing here? If I remove {{#prettify} and {{/prettify}} it works (but it is not pretty-printed!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helper was built to be used in assemble so there's a `register` method that needs to be called to work:

```
var handlebars = require("handlebars");
var helpers = require('prettify');
helpers.register(handlebars);

var templateHtml = "{{#prettify}}<div class='entry'><h1>{{title}}</h1><div class='body'>{{body}}</div></div>{{/prettify}}";
var templater = handlebars.compile(templateHtml);
var transformedHtml = templater({
    title: "Hello World",
    body: "De kat krabt de krullen van de trap"
});
console.log(transformedHtml);
```

That should work. Notice that prettify returns a Handlebars.SafeString() so `transformedHtml` will be a javascript object unless you add more markup outside of the `prettify` tags. You'll see what I mean by running it with and without spaces at the beginning and ending of the `templateHtml` string.

Comment: Hi doowb, that did definitly do the job. Could you add this to the documentation on page https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helper-prettify?